# how to apply edits to text document from vscode language server?

Tags: vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

how to apply edits to text document from server side of LSP language server vscode extension?   Maybe I have to create a WorkspaceEdit structure and send a workspace/applyEdit request to the client?  Looking for some sample code I can review.

What I am looking to do: In the initial onDidChangeContent event ( when file is opened ), I want the LSP server to review the code in the opened file and possibly insert some missing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to do something similar ...
[Using this post for inspriration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57787621/how-to-create-and-edit-a-new-file-in-the-workspace-via-language-server-extension) ...
I came up with this silly function for adding new text to a file.
Note: I am calling this from my: connection.onCompletion() function

```
function addSomeText(documentURI:string, position: Position) {

// Sample function for pushing next text to an open document.

const textToAdd1: string = "You're a bozo 1";
const textToAdd2: string = "You're a bozo 2";
const textToAdd3: string = "You're a bozo 3";
const insertPosition1: Position = Position.create(position.line + 1, 0);
const insertPosition2: Position = Position.create(position.line + 2, 0);
const insertPosition3: Position = Position.create(position.line + 3, 0);

let workspaceChange = new WorkspaceChange();
let textChange = workspaceChange.getTextEditChange(documentURI);
textChange.insert(insertPosition1, textToAdd1);
textChange.insert(insertPosition2, textToAdd2);
textChange.insert(insertPosition3, textToAdd3);

// pass these edits to the client to apply:
let reply = connection.workspace.applyEdit(workspaceChange.edit);
console.log (reply);}
```